# Meteor.userId() lost on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

I use the Meteor.userId() to check if the user has logged in or not. This works well when the user is not logged in(Meteor.userId() is null) and when the user has logged in(Meteor.userId() is not null) however if the user is logged in and the browser is refreshed Meteor.userId() is lost.

What are the community recommendations to keep track of whether the user has logged in or not? Should I redirect the user to the login page if the user has logged in and the browser is refreshed? Should I keep the Meteor.userId() in local storage after the user has logged in(I don’t think it will work)?

**Update 1:** The MainNavBar shows if the user is logged in or not based on `Meteor.userId()` in a method call to App.vue.

**MainNavBar.vue**

```
<li class="nav-item d-xl-block" v-if="(this.$root.currentUserId==null)">
            <router-link class="nav-link" v-bind:to="{ name: 'register' }">Register</router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item d-xl-block" v-else>
            <a class="nav-link" href='' data-cy="logout" v-on:click="Logout()">Log out</a>
          </li>
```

**App.vue:**

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
export default 
{
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('layout', ['showCart',]),
  },
  meteor: 
  {
    currentUserId()
    {
      return Meteor.userId();
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**Update 1:**
Based on the [comment](https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor/issues/118#issuecomment-281385543), I need to use [global navigation guards](http://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) that will make the router wait for the user subscription to be ready.

I have the following code which redirects the user to the login page if the Meteor.userId() is not present. 
How can I change the code to make the “router wait for the user subscription to be ready”, using [Meteor.loggingIn()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loggingIn). Meteor.loggingIn() is a reactive data source.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => 
  {
    //I need to wait here till Meteor.loggingIn() returns true? 
    let loggingIn= Meteor.loggingIn();
    if (loggingIn && Meteor.userId() == null && 
      to.name ==='dashboard'
    {
      next('/login');
    }
    else 
    {
      next();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Are you using `vue-meteor`? If so, [this thread](https://github.com/meteor-vue/vue-meteor/issues/118) may be useful.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWeldon for your input. I am using vue-meteor.I will have a look at the link you have provided.

Comment: Hello @DavidWeldon, I have updated the question with my analysis. I am stuck at how to make the  router wait for the user subscription to be ready. Would you have any inputs?